# How to get data from DateField format in bootstrap 3 datepicker?

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying get a publish date field for my posts using `Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker`. I am having problems while synching formats. 
My model is a datefield:

```
publish = models.DateField()
```

I use `django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker`

```
class GalleryForm(forms.ModelForm):
     publish = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
        widget=DateTimePicker(options={ "format": "DD.MM.YYYY",
                                       "pickTime": False}))
     class Meta:
      model=Gallery      
      fields = [ "title", "slug", "description",  "publish" ]
```

I use Class Based Createview:

```
class GalleryCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  form_class = GalleryForm
  template_name = "galleries/gallery_form.html"

  success_url = "/galleries/"

  def form_valid(self, form):

    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    return super(GalleryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and I use crispy forms also in my form templates and a script

```
    <form method="post" class="form-inline">
        ...
        {{form|crispy}}
        ...   
   </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#id_publish').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,

             icons: {
                    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                    date: "fa fa-calendar",
                    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
                },
            /*remove this line if you want to use time as well */
        });
      });
    </script>
```

how can I fix my datefield format error ?

Thanks

Comment: what the bootstrap version? django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker only works with bootstrap 3.

Comment: I found my own mistake . input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,  must be a list.